# How to make voice assistants to handle scientific terminology?

Tags: neural-network, nlp, voice-recognition

As a POC i would like to explore how i can make alexa skill or google home action to understand non English words,like chemical names ,scientific terminology.
Google Cloud Speech to text api allows to add a context but not a full grown solution.
How to approach this problem?

Comment: This is an awfully broad question. Your best bet is to experiment with one approach, then come back to us when you're stuck on the technical parts of your implementation.

Comment: One kind of hacky technique you could use to get around this is just to test what Alexa or Google hears when you say those words and create a list of synonyms based on that. So if you say "Plutonium" and Alexa hears "pluto knee um," you could add that as a synonym for Plutonium. Again, not a great solution, but maybe it could hold you over until Google and Alexa have the built in capabilities you need.